# Differentiate velocity in regards to distance

Tags: derivatives, classical-mechanics

Working on a bit of mechanics at the moment. I'm trying to arrive at a textbook formula but am taking a slightly different approach, however, I don't arrive at the right answer and was hoping one of you guys could find where I go wrong.

(v^2)(d/dx) = (v^2)(dt/dx)(d/dt) : Using chain rule = (v^2)(1/v)(d/dt) = (v)(d/dt) = a

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is $a$? in the last step?

Comment: a = acceleration. Differentiate velocity in regards to time and you get acceleration.

Comment: You must be careful with your notation $v\frac{d}{dt} \ne \frac{dv}{dt}$

Comment: What do you mean? (y)(d/dx) = dy/dx. Same thing.

Comment: No, it is not. Think about this example $y(t)=1$, in this cae you have on the left $d/dt$ which is an operator. And on the right $0$ which is a number!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:
$$\frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dx}} = \frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dv}}\frac{{dv}}{{dx}} = 2v\frac{{dv}}{{dx}}$$
$$v = \frac{{dx}}{{dt}}$$
$$\boxed{\frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dx}} = 2v\frac{{dv}}{{dx}} = 2\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}\frac{{dv}}{{dx}} = 2\frac{{dv}}{{dt}} = 2a}$$

If the first step confuses you, let $u = v^2$:
$$\frac{{du}}{{dv}} = \frac{d}{{dv}}\left( {{v^2}} \right) = 2v$$\
$$\frac{{du}}{{dx}} = \frac{{du}}{{dv}}\frac{{dv}}{{dx}} = 2v\frac{{dv}}{{dx}}$$

Comment: Hey, yeah, this is what they have. I was more wondering why mine doesn't work and where I went wrong.

Comment: Your notation is off...${v^2}\frac{d}{{dx}}$ should be $$\frac{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}{{dx}}$$ ${v^2}\frac{{dt}}{{dx}}\frac{d}{{dt}}$ should be $$\frac{{dt}}{{dx}}\frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dt}} = \frac{1}{v}\frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dt}}$$ You can't get from that to $\frac{{d\left( {\frac{{{v^2}}}{v}} \right)}}{{dt}} = \frac{{dv}}{{dt}}$.... What you could do is use the chain rule to get $$\frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dt}} = \underbrace {\frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dv}}}_{2v}\underbrace {\frac{{dv}}{{dt}}}_a = 2v \cdot a$$... (continued in next comment)...

Comment: ...so...$$\frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dx}} = \frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dt}}\frac{{dt}}{{dx}} = \underbrace {\frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dv}}\frac{{dv}}{{dt}}}_{\frac{{d\left( {{v^2}} \right)}}{{dt}} = 2v \cdot a} \cdot \underbrace {\frac{{dt}}{{dx}}}_{\frac{1}{v}} = 2v \cdot a \cdot \frac{1}{v} = 2a$$